Can Spring prioritize which Content-Type to respond with
I have a Spring MVC backend Controller which I would like to have respond with different media types. In the case where the client indicates it accepts multiple media types, I would like the server to be able to prioritize which media type to respond with.
Specifically, I have methods annotated with:
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/mbean/attribute",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)

and
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/mbean/attribute",
      produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)

From my testing, if the client indicates support for multiple media types, as in sending the header:
Accept: text/plain, application/octet-stream

Spring will respond with the first supported type in the list. (At least with my basic setup). Since I don't control the client's request, I would like the server to prioritize sending the response as application/octet-stream regardless of the order of the types.
I've googled a bunch, but couldn't find any examples of doing this and thus haven't actually tried anything yet. However, I'd be surprised if Spring doesn't have some way to achieve it.

See Interceptors. You will be able to change the order of that header and forward the call and let your application do the rest.

You can configure a ContentNegotiationStrategy to return content types in the order you like.
Here is a very contrived example:
    import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
    import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer cfg) {
            cfg.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(true); // disable default handling of headers

            cfg.setDefaultContentTypeStrategy(new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes(NativeWebRequest request) {
                    List<MediaType> result = super.resolveMediaTypes(request);

                    if (result.equals(List.of(TEXT_PLAIN, APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)) {
                        // swap
                        return List.of(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, TEXT_PLAIN);
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            });
        }
    }

Disclaimer!

I have not tested this code
I have chosen to override only default Strategy as it is the less invasive option. You can also just use setStrategy(List) to override the whole list of strategies - just test your application will still work as expected after this.
Overriding default content type strategy makes it so setDefaultContentType(s) settings are ignored. If you used them prior going this route, your overridden strategy should return those default types instead of returning List.of(MediaType.ALL).


Thanks! That worked with a few minor syntactic adjustments. For my particular setup I also had to add @EnableWebMvc to the class.

@JensD, good to hear! I didn't add all the required annotations because I assumed you already have a WebMvcConfig somewhere in your project, sorry about that.
